# How to use echo inside another echo

Tags: bash, ssh, echo, sendmail

I wish to use an echo command into my bash script.

Actually I do that way =>

```
echo --- REPORT ---
echo - Report send @ $(date +%d-%m-%y_%H:%M)
echo "echo \"Subject: BACKUP-$serv\"" | cat $cheminlogs/backup-$serv.log | /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail -r $mail1 $mail2;   
echo - Report done @ $(date +%d-%m-%y_%H:%M)
```

But that's don't work when I call my sh file, that's print the echo linke but won't send me the email into the 3rd line command

If I use my command alone that's ok

```
echo "Subject: BACKUP-$serv" | cat $cheminlogs/backup-$serv.log | /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail -r $mail1 $mail2;
```

I don't know how to use the echo in the start of a new command

Perhaps I can change my email command by invertion argument but that's send me an email without textarea cat

```
cat $cheminlogs/backup-$serv.log | echo "Subject: BACKUP-$serv" | /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail -r $mail1 $mail2;
```

Comment: The answer bellow with printf won't work for me, and finally I found how to escape echo, by this way that's work correctly =>
echo 'Subject:' "BACKUP-$serv" | cat - "$cheminlogs/backup-$serv.log" | /opt/zimbra/postfix/sbin/sendmail -r $mail1 $mail2

Answer (score 2):

The form you are looking for is

```
printf 'Subject: %s\n\n' "$subject" | cat - "$server_log" | sendmail
```

The `-` means 'read from standard input'. Note that `sendmail` will expect an empty line between the header and the message body.

Comment: `echo -e` is not at all portable -- much better to use, say, `printf 'Subject: %s\n\n' "$subject"`. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX `echo` spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html. Just as importantly, this means you can send messages with backslashes inside the subject without having `echo` mangle them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, corrected!